# SSIS package not executed from trigger

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a before insert trigger which executes a SSIS package to perform some work.

It works perfectly when executed from SQL Server query window(by inserting a row in the table).

But when do the insert from java code, SSIS package doesn't gets executed. 
I am really confused as why this strange behavior is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Trigger Code :

```
USE [GreeF]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER trigger [dbo].[INS_TRG] on [dbo].[MyTrigger] for insert
as 
begin try
Declare @cmd varchar(1000)
declare @FName varchar(100)
select @FName = [FileName] from inserted
select @cmd = 'dtexec /f "\\SOME_IP\packageName.dtsx" /Set "\Package.Variables[User::FileName].Properties[Value]";"'+@FName+'"'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
print @cmd
end try
begin catch
DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

SELECT 
    @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
    @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
    @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

raiserror(@ErrorMessage,@ErrorSeverity,@ErrorState)

end catch
```

Comment: "before insert trigger which executes a SSIS package" - eeeeeeeeeeekkkkk!  I can think of only a few worse idea....

Comment: does the java code run as an identity with sufficient permissions?

Comment: @MitchWheat I agree its a bad idea. But conditions have forced me.

Comment: java code has sufficient permission to do insert update on the table & database. Normal insert statement without SSIS package code is working fine.

Comment: 1. Turn on logging in your package. I will be interested to learn whether the package isn't starting or whether it's failing out. 2. When you state it works fine when you insert from SSMS but not Java app - Are you using the *same* user account for both tests (my guess is no)

Comment: There are no logs generated when I run the package from java app. I am using the same user for both the cases.

Comment: Add code to your trigger to insert to a log table. This will establish whether it's your trigger failing or the DTEXEC call. Oh and Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeek!